# Error while running protractor-perf tests

Tags: npm, performance-testing, protractor

I have setup protractor-perf tests following the [post](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2014/11/protractor-perf-performance-regression.html) by Parshuram.

However, when I run the tests using protractor-perf command, I get the following error:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown[0m
Stacktrace:
 Error: [execute("(function(){var getTimeMs=(function(){if(window.performance)\nreturn(performance.now||performance.mozNow||performance.msNow||performance.oNow||performance.webkitNow).bind(window.performance);else\nreturn function(){return new Date().getTime();};})();var requestAnimationFrame=(function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback,1000/60);};})().bind(window);window.__RafRecorder={frames:[],flush:true,record:function(timeStamp){if(__RafRecorder.flush){__RafRecorder.frames=[];__RafRecorder.flush=false;}\n__RafRecorder.frames.push(timeStamp);requestAnimationFrame(__RafRecorder.record);},get:function(){__RafRecorder.flush=true;return __RafRecorder.frames;}};requestAnimationFrame(window.__RafRecorder.record);}());")] Error response status: 13, , UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Selenium error: Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
```

Info: Tests are run on chrome driver.
Please see if someone can help! Please let me know if more information is required.

PS: If I run the same test with protractor conf.js command, everything works fine. So, seemingly there is some issue with the protractor-perf setup OR I am missing some step somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by starting the selenium webdriver. Earlier my tests were using Chromedriver directly and thus the issue.